# Chaning table collation LIKE clause dosen't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, emoji

I recently changed hosting from Godaddy to Hostinger. This changed caused emoji not showing up properly (random characters).

So i followed up Hostinger [article](https://cpanel.hostinger.in/knowledgebase/article/id/8944) fix this issue which didn't helped.

So i tried some other mentioned solutions on SO. Which include set charset at runtime.

```
$sql = "set character_set_client=utf8";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$sql = "set character_set_connection=utf8";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$sql = "set character_set_results=utf8";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$sql = "set character_set_server=utf8";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

This also didn't do anything. So i changed my table column Collation to `utf8mb4_bin` and it fixed my emoji. All emoji are showing properly.

But now `LIKE` clause which i use for searching doesn't return anything.

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM `allfiles` WHERE `file_name` LIKE '%some name%'
```

**Edit**

I am not able to search in phpmyadmin as well with utf8mb_bin collation

> Database Server information

**Localhost**

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB - Source distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**Hostinger**

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.29-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
User: user@127.0.0.1
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**Godaddy**

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.36-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: user@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Also. Without changing column collation or specifying charset at runtime i am able to view emoji perfectly fine on localhost and godaddy.

Comment: are you looking for this reply :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638955/php-variable-and-mysql-like-query-is-not-working

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli no.. its not that issue. I am not able to search from phpmyadmin as well.

Comment: may be it's about mysql version . can you check the version of mysql on the both servers and see if there are the same ?

Comment: please , print your sql query in your question

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli updated question with more details

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my main problem.

Using `mysqli_character_set_name($con)` i got correct charset which was used `godaddy` & `localhost`. Which returned `latin1`.

So i using `mysqli_set_charset($con, "latin1");` it fixed charset which returned correct emoji.

Still not sure why changing column collation to `utf8mb4` caused LIKE clause to return no result.